# Question about Conditional Probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I had a question about conditional probabilities. Say I had the probabilities P(X), P(Y), P(Z), P(X|Y), and P(Y|Z) (assume the random variables are boolean random variables with either a true or false value). Originally I was thinking I could create the product: P(X|Y) * P(Y|Z) = P(X,Y|Z). But that seems like it would only be accurate if X was conditionally independent of Z given Y. Is this accurate?

Also, say I additionally have P(X|Z). I'm assuming P(X|Z) * P(Y|Z) =/= P(X,Y|Z) unless there's some conditional independence between X and Y given Z. Can I make any additional claims about the joint probability distribution with this information (like about P(X,Y,Z))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But that seems like it would only be accurate if X was conditionally independent of Z given Y. Is this accurate?

Indeed, that's a corollary of the definition of conditional independence.

$$\mathsf P(X,Y\mid Z)=\mathsf P(X\mid Y,Z)\,\mathsf P(Y\mid Z) \overset{X\perp Z\mid Y}= \mathsf P(X\mid Y)\,\mathsf P(Y\mid Z)$$

And likewise conditional independence of $X,Y$ when given $Z$ leads to:

$$\mathsf P(X,Y\mid Z)=\mathsf P(X\mid Y,Z)\,\mathsf P(Y\mid Z) \overset{X\perp Y\mid Z}= \mathsf P(X\mid Z)\,\mathsf P(Y\mid Z)$$

> Can I make any additional claims about the joint probability distribution with this information (like about P(X,Y,Z))?

Not particularly.   Well, if you know one of the above cases does apply, then you can make appropriate substitutions into:

$$\mathsf P(X,Y,Z)~{= \mathsf P(X,Y\mid Z)\,\mathsf P(Z)\\ = \mathsf P(X\mid Y,Z)\,\mathsf P(Y\mid Z)\,\mathsf P(Z)}$$